# how can a profile page be made for a social network in asp.net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to make a simple social network for my school project but I am not really understanding how the profile page works. should I create a different page for every user? (or automatically). And then update it when someone adds or deletes a new photo or status? or should I connect everything with database?

so any other suggestions how this can be done? I prefer to do first more. but still not sure if it can be done.

PS: javascript can be included too if its necessary. also, for pics Im going to use imgur and just implement the link in the image source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect everything with a database. Each user should be uniquely identified in the database; then add additional tables to your database that consist of each user's data ... like posts, pictures, likes, etc. Create relationships between all tables based upon each user's unique ID.

Or download free version of Visual Studio Community https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/ then install FaceBook template.

Comment: and about the pics? there would be wayyy too many, I am going to use imgur for the images, and the posts.

Comment: To add to this, based on your question it sounds like there might be a bit of a lack of understanding around reusability and dynamically populated resources. You'll want a single user profile page that populates based on which user you're looking at it for. Think about it from a website URL perspective: /profiles/?userId=1234 (for example).

Comment: @SkylerAustin I was thinking for something like mypage.com/users/userID
is it possible?

Comment: Yep. Look into Asp.Net MVC Routing

Comment: @SkylerAustin that is not what I am looking for.